# how to match a mocked call with wildcard in scala test?

Tags: scala, testing, mockito

looking for something like this:

```
    //Mockito when rawData.filter(filter) thenReturn mockInfo
    //this won't work because the parameter can only match one instance
    //but I want
    Mockito when rawDataRDD.filter(*) thenReturn mockInfo
```

so how shall I match a spied call with wildcard in Scala test ?

more explanation:

I'm looking for a spied mock in `scala test` where all calling to a RDD filter will be captured and return the specified mock result.

more generally, looking for matching functions in Scala (just like `AnyString` in java) like anyFunction to match all filter functions.

Comment: You mind putting a a complete [mcve]. I have no clue what exactly you intend to do and where things break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Matchers.any()`

```
 Mockito when rawDataRDD.filter(Matchers.any()) thenReturn mockInfo
```

Comment: awesome, thanks. why it is so difficult for me to search such thing in documentation

Comment: This should be `org.mockito.Mockito.any()` for later versions of Mockito so as not to confuse it with Hamcrest. `org.mockito.Matchers.any()` is now deprecated